# Snakemake expects at least one singularity argument, but one is provided

Tags: snakemake, singularity-container

I am running the following command with an NVIDIA Tesla GPU:
`snakemake -j all --use-singularity --singularity-args="--nv"`

It works properly, because I get the following output on the first rule (which uses a GPU):

```
Activating singularity image /project/brookings_minion/guppy_container.sif
ONT Guppy basecalling software version 4.2.2+effbaf84
config file:        /opt/ont/guppy/data/dna_r9.4.1_450bps_hac.cfg
model file:         /opt/ont/guppy/data/template_r9.4.1_450bps_hac.jsn
input path:         /project/brookings_minion/examples/fast5
save path:          /project/brookings_minion/examples/results/.temp/basecall
chunk size:         2000
chunks per runner:  512
records per file:   4000
num basecallers:    4
gpu device:         cuda:0,1
kernel path:
runners per device: 4
```

I know by the `gpu device: cuda:0,1` that the GPU is indeed available. However, at the end of the run, I am getting the following error: `__main__.py: error: argument --singularity-args: expected one argument`

I do not get this error until *after* the above command is run.
I have also tried: `snakemake -j all --use-singularity --singularity-args "--nv"`, which fails almost immediately with the same error.

Why could this be, if Snakemake seems to be able to pass the `--nv` flag to singularity?
I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might need to do quite a lot of quoting to smuggle it through. Try this:

```
--singularity-args '\\-\\-nv' \
```